# AWS Lambda Function: new Logger() sometimes appends to previous log, instead of creating a new one

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, logging, aws-lambda, python-logging

I'm working with AWS Lambda Functions (Python). In my function, I create a new Logger() object, which I use to log information throughout. It doesn't always create a new logging instance in CloudWatch. Sometimes it appends to a previous log. I don't understand the inconsistency.

I always do the logging the same way:

- joblog = Logger(service="xxx", level="INFO")
- joblog.info("xxx")

I'm executing the function via the "Test" tab, and also with scheduled events (from CloudWatch, with crontab entries).

Comment: This is normal behaviour, unrelated to your logging code. It seems that CloudWatch creates a new log file either after a specific time has elapsed, or a new Lambda container has been provisioned. Therefore, you can't control this behaviour from _within_ the Lambda function itself.

Comment: "Seems"? Looking at your gold badges, this is a pretty big window for an unknown @JohnRotenstein. Is it documented?

Comment: @roganjosh I was replying based on my experience rather than specific knowledge. That's why I provided a Comment rather than an Answer.

Comment: The log stream is [created for each new Lambda Execution Environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/operatorguide/log-structure.html).

Answer (score 0):

Per @AnonCoward's link:

From [How CloudWatch structures logs - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/operatorguide/log-structure.html):

> Each instance of a Lambda function has a dedicated log stream. If a function scales up, each concurrent instance **has its own log stream**. Each time an execution environment is reaped and a new environment is created in response to an invocation, **this generates a new log stream**. The naming convention for log streams is:
>
> `YYYY/MM/DD[Function version][Execution environment GUID]`
>
> A single execution environment **writes to the same log stream during its lifetime**. The log stream contains messages from that execution environment and also any output from your Lambda function’s code. Every message is timestamped, including your custom logs, which means you do not need to output timestamps.

Comment: I execute functions manually and from CloudWatch scheduled events. Sometimes new logs are NOT created. So, what does "scale up a function" mean?

Comment: After more Internet research, I found out that AWS Lambda has the concept of "cold" and "warm" starts.  It keeps the microVM around for a little while, in case the function is going to be called again.  Cold starts get new log streams.  Warm starts append to the last one.  I have no idea if there's a simple way to force cold starts, short of uploading new code.

Comment: You are correct. Here is a great series of articles that help truly understand how AWS Lambda operates: [Operating Lambda: Performance optimization – Part 1 | AWS Compute Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/operating-lambda-performance-optimization-part-1/)